# Compare 2 tables for changes in each columns

Tags: sql, linq, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables with close to 30 columns in each. I would like to compare each column value with one table to another and show a list of only those records that have changed. I dont think I can do this on SQL Server 2008 since I am dealing with large data sets and columns, If any of you have managed to do a similar requirement on either LINQ or SQL SERVER please request you guys to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * 
from table1
full outer join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
where table1.col1 <> table2.col1
or table1.col2 <> table2.col2
or table1.col3 <> table2.col3
...
```

Comment: but isnt this a longer process considering I am dealing with close to 30columns easily

Comment: You can write up 30 column names in a few minutes right?

Comment: #gaganHR: these are your specs and this is the solution ...

Comment: Note: This assumes there is a non-changing ID. The OP should've mentioned that.